# Live streaming with dynamic playlist wowza

Tags: mysql, live-streaming, wowza

I have checked on the wowza server on creating and using the playlist for live streaming using the smil file. However the set back with that option is that I have to restart the application if I do any changes on the playlist file, because the playlist file is loaded at the start of the application.

What I want to do is that I want to create a wowza module where I can load the playlist of videos from the database (mysql) dynamically and play them in the order in the database. While the live streaming is playing I should be able to do the changes in the order by changing on the database and the module should pickup the next video file from the database. Can someone help me on how I can load dynamic playlist from the database on wowza live streaming.

I'm using wowza 4.0 streaming engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module in the Add-on Collection (http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?113-Module-Collection) called ModuleStreamControl: 
[http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?187-How-to-control-Stream-class-streams-dynamically-(ModuleStreamControl)](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?187-How-to-control-Stream-class-streams-dynamically-%28ModuleStreamControl%29)

This handles the dynamic playlist side of things and could be modified to talk to your database.

I would suggest the Wowza forums or Wowza's email support would be a good place to get additional info on this, if needed.

Scott

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have posted the question on wowza forums.

Comment: Hey @user1599669, Can you give me the link to the question you posted on wowza regarding this? I need to use dynamic playlist to stream audio.

Comment: This is the URL for the forum post -  http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?36026-Live-streaming-with-dynamic-video-scheduling&p=135792 But the details given there is not straight forward and you need to workaround with the server side modules to make it work.